# message attributes are not retained in AWS SQS Dead letter queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have SQS which triggers AWS lambda, and its needs to do some process and upload to some other place. I have dead letter queu associated to it for a retry of 3 attempts. Lets if the upload is failing for reason for more than 3 times then it will be moved to dead later queue.
When I receives the messages in the SQS queue then I am getting message attributes coming as:

```
{ApproximateReceiveCount=3, SentTimestamp=123, SenderId=xyz-123, ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=123}
```

Now the upload API is fixed and when I try to redrive the AWS Dead letter queue then I'm getting the message attribute `ApproximateReceiveCount` again starting from 1, it must start from 4

I have the set up like when we redrive then it will go back to the original and requeue from there.

I tried adding a new lambda function to the dead letter queue still I'm getting `ApproximateReceiveCount` again starting from 1

Answer (score 1):

> Now the upload API is fixed and when I try to redrive the AWS Dead letter queue then I'm getting the message attribute ApproximateReceiveCount again starting from 1, it must start from 4

That's not possible. The message was moved to another queue. The new queue it was moved to keeps track of the receive count separately. Thus it is starting over at `1`.

> I tried adding a new lambda function to the dead letter queue still
> I'm getting ApproximateReceiveCount again starting from 1

The code in this second Lambda function should be updated to assume that it is always pulling from the DLQ, so the receive count is always `3` more than what is in the `ApproximateReceiveCount`.

Comment: The solution you mentioned worked out very well.